# Set sequence of on/off ink in points for a circle in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I know how to change the sequence of on/off ink points for a line, and I want to do the same for a circle with not fill. A circle does not seem to have the same set_dashes() function, and set_linestyle() only accepts strings like 'solid', but not a tuple of (on ticks, off ticks).

Here's a minimal example, I would like the circle to have the same dashes like the line plot.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Circle


fig = plt.figure() 
ax = fig.add_subplot(111) 

# plot a line with dashes
line = plt.plot(np.arange(2))[0]
plt.setp(line, 'dashes')
line.set_dashes((20,2))

# plot a circle with dashes
circle = Circle(xy=(0,0), radius=1, fill=False, ec='b', lw=2, linestyle='dashed')
plt.setp(circle, 'linestyle')
ax.add_artist(circle)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to generate the points for the circle 'by hand'. Here is an minimum example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Circle

fig = plt.figure() 
ax = fig.add_subplot(111) 

# plot a line with dashes
line = plt.plot(np.arange(2))[0]
plt.setp(line, 'dashes')
line.set_dashes((20,2))

# plot a circle with dashes
Radius = 1
xC = np.linspace(0, Radius, 100)
yC = np.sqrt(Radius**2 - xC**2)
line = plt.plot(xC, yC)[0]
plt.setp(line, 'dashes')
line.set_dashes((20,2))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Several improvements can easily be made - you may have already thought of these but I thought I would add them just in case.  Firstly to get the circle to be 'circular' we should use an equal aspect axes:

```
fig = plt.figure() 
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')
```

Then secondly you may want to plot the whole extent of the circle. This is most easily done by plotting the two sides separately:

```
# plot a circle with dashes
Radius = 1
xC = np.linspace(-Radius, Radius, 100)
yC_positive = np.sqrt(Radius**2 - xC**2)
yC_negative = -np.sqrt(Radius**2 - xC**2)

line = plt.plot(xC, yC_positive)[0]
plt.setp(line, 'dashes')
line.set_dashes((20,2))

line = plt.plot(xC, yC_negative)[0]
plt.setp(line, 'dashes')
line.set_dashes((20,2))
```

Putting all this together we get

[image]

I've purposefully left the colors different for the two sides to indicate which is which.